# chrome extension icon is not changing

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a simple Chrome Extension for changing the extension icon every 300 milliseconds. But my code is not working. Below is my code:

```
setTimeout(updateIcon, 300);
var min = 1;
var max = 5;
var current = min;

function updateIcon() {
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"icon" + current + ".png"});
  current++;

  if (current > max)
    current = min;
}
```

What's wrong with the above code?

Comment: Where have you kept the above code block : content script or Background page ?

Comment: @Ankit,i have the code in background

Comment: are you able to update icon at least once? maybe declare the function before the `setTimeout`?

Comment: `setTimeout` will call the function just once. I think you are looking for `setInterval`.

Comment: @Ankit,Thanks,you are correct.setInterval is working.kindly put your comment as answer.

Comment: @Ankit I think it was already told to you, but you should look into canvas-based animating. It will be smoother than loading it from a file every time. See `drawIconAtRotation()` in [this sample](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/extensions/gmail/background.js). Also, the documentation [says](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#tips), I quote, _"**Don't** constantly animate your icon. That's just annoying."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` will call the function just once. I think you are looking for `setInterval`.

```
setInterval(updateIcon, 300);
```

Comment: also note that this is not a good way to animate an icon. look at the official docs and use canvas.